# How to exclude certain columns from being filtered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of data with order dates, orderer and product id etc. 
To the right of the table I have a visualization of the estimated amount of days until completed.

[image: Picture of the visualization]

How can I make the visualization not be affected by the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day Highfi,

What kind of visualization do you have?  Some kind of visualization that floats on top of your schedule will work. A pivot chart is an example of something that will not be impacted by the filtering, a standard chart will, but only in it will show only the data that is not  hidden by the filter.

An easy solution depending on what you want to accomplish is taking a screen cap or something similar and paste it into your workbook.

Hopefully, this will help a bit.

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the suggestions! The visualization is to show manufacturing workers how many days the products are estimated to take. As of now it is just cells with IF-statements which seems inefficient. (I just took over the project and am new to Excel). I tried creating a chart with the data which worked out OK. But I will definitely try your suggestions.

Thanks a lot for the help! :)